# How to update partial document in single command?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
{
   _id : ...,
   key : { 
        a : 1,
        b : 2,
        c : 3
   }
}
```

And I will update this collection with this:

```
var data = {
    b : 4,
    c : 5
};
```

And I want my document be update to this:

```
{
   _id : ...,
   xxx : { 
        a : 1,
        b : 4,
        c : 5
   }
}
```

So if I do this:

```
db.myColl.update(  _id , { $set: {"xxx": data } );
```

it will end up a document like this:

```
{
   _id : ...,
   xxx: { 
      b : 4,
      c : 5
   }
}
```

So I have to do it twice:

```
db.myColl.update(  _id , { $set: {"xxx.b": data.b } );
db.myColl.update(  _id , { $set: {"xxx.c": data.c } );
```

Is it possible to do it in single command?

Comment: No, thats the only way I have seen. `$set` replaces any sub properties with the new values, so if its missing one, it considers that deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by combining both of the `$set` terms into a single update:

```js
db.myColl.update(_id, { $set: {"xxx.b": data.b, "xxx.c": data.c } });
```

Comment: ... I would even say this _should_ be done that way -- so the update is atomic. When the OP uses two separate updates, there is a possibility for concurrent reads on the DB to see a a partially updated document.